# d3 - enter - appends too many elements, as if data is not bound

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm asking this not to get code working, but to make sure I'm understanding d3 correctly. I have created a d3 bar chart example that I'm using to better understand d3's data binding and update patterns. Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/qP9j9/22/

The fiddle explains the problem best, but I will also attempt an explanation below:

I have split out the data binding and the view into two separate functions:

```
var updateData = function() {

  data = generateRandomData();
  chart = d3.select('.chart').selectAll('div').data(data);
  y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, Math.floor(d3.max(data))]).range([1,300]);

  updateChart();

};

var updateChart = function() {

  var margin = 1;
  var barWidth = (parseInt(d3.select('.chart').style('width'))/15) - margin;

  chart.transition()
        .style('height', function(d) { return y(d) + 'px' })
        .style('width', function() { return barWidth + 'px' })
        .style('left', function(d, i) { return (i * (barWidth+margin)) + 'px' });

  chart.enter().append('div')
        .style('height', function() { return 0; })
        .style('width', function() { return barWidth + 'px' })
        .style('left', function(d, i) { return (i * (barWidth+margin)) + 'px' })
        .transition()
        .style('height', function(d) { return y(d) + 'px' });

  chart.exit().remove();

};
```

On resize, I'm running the updateChart function. My thought there is that I'd rather not bind the data when it doesn't change, just update the view. When the data actually changes, I run updateData function.

Oddly, the updateData function needs to run twice in order for things to work correctly. If updateData is called only once (when page first loads), then when updateChart runs, the enter() function appends the data all over again. So when the page resizes, you just get duplicate dom elements.

I have researched this as much as possible, including looking at some of the "Similar Questions" that were suggested, and I can certainly "work around" the problem easily enough. But it feels like there's something fundamental I'm not understanding.

Comment: Adding d3.selectAll('.chart div').remove(); to updateChart function solves the problem, but would qualify as hacky work around alluded to.  Not sure this is helpful, but like to see this answered by d3 pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea behind D3 is to link data and document, so it's a bad idea to separate the two like you've done. In particular, you're using `.enter()` and `.exit()` selections, which doesn't work properly if you haven't explicitly bound data before. In your case, the `.enter()` selection contains the previous selection, which is why everything is added twice.

My recommendation is two have *one* function that updates, not two separate ones. If you absolutely do want to separate them, you need to put handling of the `.enter()` and `.exit()` selections in the `updateData()` function, as I've done in your updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qP9j9/23/).

Comment: I see. So in other words, I shouldn't be concerned about "binding the data to document" just to redraw the chart, even if the data hasn't changed. I was sort of needlessly separating things that d3 doesn't really want separated. Although your update to my fiddle works and keeps the separation I was looking for, I could really just do it all in one function without a problem. All the updateData function really needs to do is generate new data.

Comment: Technically you don't need to bind new data if you only want to transition existing DOM elements (which is what my fiddle does). You may want to have separate `redraw` and `updateData` functions that do the respective things -- this is essentially what it is already. It's usually easier to put everything together though to avoid confusion, especially if you're just starting with D3.